# How obtain error message when exporting data from LibreOffice Base to Calc and freezing occurs?

Tags: libreoffice, database

[Ubuntu 12.04] When exporting large (100 MB) data from a table in LibreOffice 3.5.2.2 Base embedded HSQLDB to a Calc spreadsheet using the procedure outlined in LibreOffice Help, LibreOffice Base and Calc freeze after ~14 min. I can move the cursor though.
The same process with a small table (~10 kB) works all right.

How to obtain an error message? 
Is it really necessary to install the DEB program package libreoffice-dbg and using gdb or strace?

Answer (score 0):

Try running **libreoffice** from a terminal. See Help for various **command line options**